# Applied Statistics for Engineers and Scientists: Probability of a combination

Tags: probability, combinations

A student has 12 movies. Among these movies, 6 are Marvel, 3 are Star Wars and the other 3 are Lord of the Rings. Now if 4 movies are randomly selected for Movie Night this month, what is the probability that: 
(Round to 3 decimals)

a.  at least 1 movie from each series is picked?

b.  all Star Wars movies are picked?

I was able to find the number of combinations for selecting 4 from the 12, but don't know what the next steps are.

Comment: The technical name for the distribution which you don't need to learn is [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).  If you wish to read more about it there, go ahead.  The end result is that we pick which four movies they are satisfying the desired conditions.  To have at least one from each series, we can break into cases based on which series got two movies, pick which two movies from that series, and pick which one movie from the remaining series we have.  In (b) we pick which 1 other movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming movies can *not* be picked twice, there are as you say $\binom{12}{4}$ equally likely selections of four movies possible where order doesn't matter.

When counting the number of ways in which we watch all three starwars movies and one other movie, the only missing piece of information is what that one other movie is.  It can be chosen in $9$ ways, making the probability $\dfrac{9}{\binom{12}{4}}$

When counting the number of ways in which we watch at least one movie of each type, recognize that there will be one movietype that we watch two movies from and the remaining types we watch one movie from.  Break into cases based on which type had two movies watched.  Once broken into that case, pick which movie or movies from each type were the ones watched.  Finish by applying rule of product and rule of sum and divide by the number of possibilities to get a probability of:

$$\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{6}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{6}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{12}{4}}$$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, that's what I ended up doing. Glad to see that I chose right.

Answer (score -1):

the thing that you need is the multinomial distribution.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

1.)I am assuming picking with replacement
Here you have to extract n=4 movies and the probability of getting a marvel movie ,$p_m$ is  $\frac{6}{12}$ . Similarily $p_w=\frac{3}{12}$ and $p_l=\frac{3}{12}$

Let $X_j$ denote the number of movies that you got from type $j$. 
1.) There are only three ways to get one movie from each ( $X_m=2,X_w=1,X_l=1$) or( $X_m=1,X_w=2,X_l=1$) or ( $X_m=1,X_w=1,X_l=2$)
The toal probability of this is 
$$\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}p_m^2 p_w p_l+\frac{4!}{1!2!1!}p_m p_w^2 p_l+\frac{4!}{1!1!2!}p_m p_w p_l^2$$

Comment: Thanks. We were just taught permutations and conditions. So, I was thinking that I'd find the combination of each movie, using the idea that you did with X_j, then adding those together and dividing them by the overall combination N=(12  4). Would that work?

Comment: "*I am assuming picking with replacement*"  I can't think of any movie night clubs who would be okay with rewatching the same movie multiple times in such a short timeframe.  This seems like an incorrect assumption to me.